# Retriving the value of a registry string in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, text-manipulation

In a batch file, I'm reading the value of 'ProfileImagePath' like so...

```
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\%thisusersid%" /v ProfileImagePath') do set "thisuserprofile=%%a"
```

This populates the variable %thisuserprofile% with the following....

```
 ProfileImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\Users\joebloggs
```

How do i go about instead JUST getting the value, so...

%THISUSERPROFILE%="C:\Users\joebloggs" for example?

I know there is already a windows variable for the users profile, however the parent script is running in the system context, so i have to go the long way around, ascertaining the users SID and profile location etc.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Yes, indeedy! thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This was how i did it...

```
 for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\%USERSID%" /v ProfileImagePath') do set "thisuserprofile=%%~b"
```

echo %thisuserprofile%

Output is just the profile path :)